# How do I pass a function pointer from a class into another function in C++

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

I am having some trouble with passing a function that is a member of the class 'F' to a function that is the member of class 'X'.I get the error 'error: no match function for call to X::call()'
Sorry if the solution is really simple, I'm still fairly new to C++

My code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class X{
public:
    void call (void (*func)()){
        func();
    }
};

class F{
public:
    void Function(){
        cout<<"hello";
    }
};

int main()
{
    X x;
    F f;

    x.call(f.Function);

    return 0;
}
```

basically I'm just trying to pass the function from class F into class X call function.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: member function != regular function, make `F::Function` `static`.

Comment: You tagged your question with `member-function-pointers` but `void (*func)()` is a regular function pointer not a member function pointer. A member function pointer (of the class F) would be `void (F::*func)()`.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is something that any decent text-book, tutorial or class should have mentioned: A non-static member function is *not* like a non-member function. The difference being that a (non-static) member function needs an object to be called on, and non-member functions doesn't. This makes the pointers to each very different.

You could solve your problem with e.g. [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function):

```
void call(std::function<void()> func);
```

Then pair it with a [lambda expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda):

```
x.call([&]()
{
    f.function();
});
```

---

As an alternative, you could use templates for the function type:

```
template<typename F>
void call(F func);
```

If you use a template, you can also use [`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind):

```
x.call(std::bind(&F::Function, f));
```

---

For completeness, here's the other alternatives mentioned in comments:

- The first suggest making `F::Function` a `static` member function, which means it's a member of the *class* and don't need any specific object to be called:

  ```
  static void Function();
  ```
- The second comment suggest creating a pointer to a `F` member function:

  ```
  class F;  // Forward declare the F class

  class X
  {
  public:
      void call(void (F::*func)());
  };
  ```